# Dropbox/Webhost hybrid?

Tags: file-synchronization, web-server

Is there anything out there that can work as a Dropbox style service and also serve select pages you uploaded which have server-side code?

Maybe also having some kind of integrated client - similar to how Dropbox has a folder on your local PC which will sync stuff to the cloud once you're connected to the internet?

I would really love something that can give me an SQL database to play with, also.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Drive](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) is the world’s most popular cloud storage system offering that enables you to store your documents, photos, music, videos etc. all in one place.More apps can be integrated into google drive to form a single held application,that's powered by cloud and client integration.Perfect!

It automatically syncs all your data with your mobile devices and your computer, meaning every device that is linked to your account receives the updates and shows the changes you have made. 
For individual users who require basic sharing capacity and storage up to 15 GB, Google Drive comes for free. The most you can pay for it is $299.99 for 30 TB of storage.

Google Drive monitors your changes too for the past 30 days, enabling you to go back and redo/undo the changes you made.

---

Therefore;when it comes to something that can give you an SQL database to play with,simply **Google drive** integrates with **SkyviaSkyvia** which is a perfect tool to import & export cloud and relational data to Google Drive. It provides powerful filter settings to filter data to export, and is able to export data not only from a single object, but also add fields from the related objects.

For instance;Import CSV files from Google Drive to cloud applications and relational databases with Skyvia. Skyvia can import several CSV files at once, import a single CSV file to several related Google Drive objects, use various string and numeric expressions for mapping, etc. Powerful mapping features enable you to import data with the structure different from the structure of target objects.

Tehnical Details:
 - 1.Devices Supported

Windows,
Linux,
Android,
iPhone/iPad,
Mac,
Web-based
Windows Mobile

- Language Support

USA,
UK,
Canada,
International,
China,
Germany,
India,
Japan,
Spain,
France,
Russia

- Pricing Model

Free,
One-time payment

- Customer Types

Small Business,
Large Enterprises,
Medium Business,
Freelancers

- Deployment

Cloud Hosted

Comment: I hope [it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/WPtLkVSznts) would be interesting for you to read

Comment: @Alex Technical problems have to be always fixed or solved.And that's why we are in for software recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at open sourced project [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) that is in stage of very active development by people who really knows what they are doing.

It use behind scene the same network model as torrent but it narrow sharing only to authorized devices and always use strong encryption. The core feature - is that your data not shared with any third parties such as Google, Dropbox, it is completely private solutions. Software can be used locally only (inside of your local network) or it may sync data across multiple devices without need to open firewall ports or do some extra networking adjustments. It can run in master mode (where one node can be setup as read only for all other devices) or can share data bidirectionally in both ways. It support versioning, so accidentally removed data on one of devices can be easily restored. You may setup one of the node on the server and another one on development computer and all your changes that made on development side will be synced automatically to the server. Software written in GoLang which is mean it is compiled native code where nice point of that it statically compiled, which in turn it means it doesn't require installation of multiple dependencies that simplify installation just by dropping a single executable file. Another good part of using GoLang in this project - it that code can be compiled to various (practically all)  platforms (Windows, Linux, all BSD flavors as well smartphones). Software management is done via nice and easy understandable web interface that simplify it management from any devices that has browser(it possible to manage over command line too).
As I said previously, by utilizing torrent model of communication with many participating devices, speed of synchronization could be limited by network capability only. Another good parts of this software is that it use technology similar to `rsync` which is means, if one having a huge file and there was just a little changes then the only this changes will be synced over network instead of re-transmitting the whole file again and again.

As about MySQL, I would suggest you to use standard SSH protocol by employing reverse port feature. This way you can connect to remote database over encrypted channel and it would behave like you sitting on the same machine that running MySQL itself. For the backup purpose - IMO best solution it when you backup databases with appropriate tools that comes with MySQl and if it needed, sync it to external machine by employing `syncthing`

[image: SyncThing]
<sub>(source: [syncthing.net](https://syncthing.net/images/screenshot-720.jpg))</sub>